# Missing Return Stament

Tags: java

```
public Company getCompanyByID (int ID) {

    boolean hasKey = Company.AllCompanies.containsKey(ID);
    if (hasKey == true) {

    Company C = Company.AllCompanies.get(ID);
    return C;
    }
// In this case IDE says Missing Return Statement
} 



public Company getCompanyByID (int ID) {

    boolean hasKey = Company.AllCompanies.containsKey(ID);
    if (hasKey == true) {
    //In this case, if condition based statement can't be written, which is written outside the code block where it should be

    }
    Company C = Company.AllCompanies.get(ID);
    return C;

}
```

First, I want to check that the Key supplied as a parameter is contained in the TreeMap or not? If the Key supplied in a parameter is a valid key which has a value entry in the TreeMap, then I want to return the Value, in this case, it is an Object of a class Company.

Comment: For a start `if (hasKey = true)` is wrong.  BTW what is your question?

Comment: Ok and otherwise? You should return something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A java method must return the declared return type in any case (/in any if-else branch) ... or throw an (declared or runtime) exception.

So you should be clear what to do/what to return, when **not** `AllCompanies.containsKey(ID)`.

Possible solutions:

- return `null` (null is like (almost) any type ... expect: boolean, int, short, byte,...double ("value types"))
- throw a (custom or general purpose) exception (e.g. `throw new IllegalArgumentException("No customer found for id:" + ID);` [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html)
- or maybe even: create a `new` Company , add it to AllCompanies , and return this. (but then the method should be named `getOrCreate...` ..for future developers;)
- all other alternatives...

Answer (score 2):

what the compiler is trying to tell you is that you are not returning anything if `hasKey == false`. Also, `hasKey = true` is an assignment and not a boolean condition. You should be using `if(hasKey)`

```
public Company getCompanyByID (int ID) {

    boolean hasKey = Company.AllCompanies.containsKey(ID);
    if (hasKey) {

        Company C = Company.AllCompanies.get(ID);
        return C;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return a value outside an if statement as well..

Plus, `hasKey=true` is wrong